# Construct a datetime.datatime from datetime.date and constants?

Tags: python

For the following code

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
datetime.now().date() + timedelta(days=1) + timedelta(hours=14, minutes=23)
```

I expect it returns (assuming today is June 8, 2022)

```
datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 9, 14, 23, 0)
```

However, it returned

```
datetime.date(2022, 6, 9)
```

The time part is ignored?

Comment: It might help if you described what you're trying to accomplish. There's probably an easier way to construct the datetime object you want. If you're trying to set a specific time, you could try using `datetime.replace`. Calling `datetime.date` gives you a `date` object, which drops time information altogether..

Comment: I want to get the date time of next day, e.g., at 14:23 (can be and parameters passed)

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
datetime.combine(datetime.now().date(), datetime.min.time()) + timedelta(days=1) + timedelta(hours=14, minutes=23)
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: “This should do the trick.”  Did you by chance test it?  If yes, the statement should be more definitive.  If not, why not?

Comment: As datetime.date object doesn't preserve any information about time, you need to convert it into datetime object before adding timedelta.

Comment: `datetime.min.time()` seems like it would more obviously be done with just `time()` (tweaking the import to get it along with `datetime`). `datetime.min` is about the earliest representable `datetime`, and it's mostly coincidence it happens to have a `time` of all zeroes; you may as well just construct `time()` directly (which is documented to default to all zeroes in a more obvious way).

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the date and time parts separately, and then combine them with the classmethod [`datetime.combine`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine). This avoids some of the complexities that can arise when performing calculations on datetimes when you really only care about the date portion.

```
import datetime


def tomorrow() -> datetime.date:
    return datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)


time_part = datetime.time(hour=14, minute=23)
end_of_the_world = datetime.datetime.combine(tomorrow(), time_part)
print(end_of_the_world)
```

which prints

```
datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 9, 14, 23)
```

Comment: Hmm... I came up with other solutions, but I think I like this one better than either of mine for straightforwardness. Up-voted.

Comment: There seems be some issues when using timezone. I've posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72551977/earlier-datetime-is-greater-than-later-datetime

Answer (score 1):

To get today as a `datetime`, you can do:

```
today = datetime(*datetime.now().timetuple()[:3])
```

which converts the `datetime` to a `tuple` of arguments, slices to keep only year, month and day, and constructs a new `datetime` from it (all the other arguments to the constructor are optional and default to zero, so you get a `datetime` corresponding to midnight of that day).

You can then follow that up with:

```
today + timedelta(days=1, hours=14, minutes=23)
```

to get your desired result.

Alternatively, a simpler way to go about this is to just use [the `replace` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace):

```
now = datetime.now()
tomorrow_at_1423 = now.replace(day=now.day+1, hour=14, minute=23, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

which performs the fixups rather more directly as a single operation.