# Earlier datetime is greater than later datetime?

Tags: python

The following code should set `b` larger than `a` because `b` is basically a copy of `a` with minute set to zero. However, it show that `a < b` is True? Maybe the parameter assigning of `tzinfo=est_tz` is incorrect?

```
import datetime
import pytz

est_tz = pytz.timezone("America/New_York")
a = datetime.datetime.now(est_tz)
b = datetime.datetime.combine(
    a.date(),
    datetime.time(hour=a.hour, minute=0), # minute is set to 0 so a > b
    tzinfo=est_tz  # wrong?
)
print(a)
print(b)
print(a < b)  # Print True
a, b
```

Output:

```
2022-06-08 16:33:39.074224-04:00
2022-06-08 16:00:00-04:56
True
```

Why `b` has timezone of `-04:56`?

And `a` has the value of `datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 8, 16, 33, 39, 74224, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)`, and `b` has the value of `datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 8, 16, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>)`.

Comment: bug: you might want to read through `pytz` docs. i think it explains the exact issue you were noticing.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `b` assignment to the following and it worked. use `pytz.localize()` to convert the value, instead of setting the parameter of `tzinfo`.

```
b = est_tz.localize(
  datetime.datetime.combine(
    a.date(),
    datetime.time(hour=a.hour, minute=0), # minute is set to 0 so a > b
  )
)
```